# Read file after EOF reached

Tags: c

The code snippet has an EOF after the while loop, the file has to be reopened again afterwards - fopen is reused. My question is if there is a way to avoid this clumsy double usage of fopen or not to use EOF in some way?

```
if (!(f=fopen("D:\\C\\Test.txt", "r"))) 
        {   
          printf("File not existing\n");
        }
while ((next=fgetc(f))!=EOF){
    if (next=='1') num++;
}

printf("%d\n", num);

  f=fopen("D:\\C\\Test.txt", "r");
   while (fgets(buf, 1000, f)!=NULL)
            printf("%s", buf);
```

Hope I was clear enough.

Comment: You can fseek to the beginning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you should `fclose()` before reopening, if you do the reopen. If you don't, you are 'leaking' computer resources — you have an open file stream that you can't access.

Second, you can [`fseek()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fseek.html) to the start of the file, or you can [`rewind()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rewind.html) the file, without needing to reopen the file:

```
fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_SET);
rewind(f);
```

You should also note that your code as shown reports that it failed to open the file on the first time, but proceeds to use the file just as if it had succeeded.  This is unlikely to lead to happiness.  You should also check the success of the second open (if you do the reopen). Just because the file was there a second ago doesn't mean it is still there (though the chance of failure is slight, I grant you).

Comment: Tnx for replying, used rewind and prob solved. I spott now it's not properly opening. How am I supposed to fix that as well?

Comment: If the file is not opening, there's presumably a problem with the file name.  You're on a Windows machine; you have, apparently, a `D:` drive with a folder `D:\\C` in it for your C projects.  Does the file `Test.txt` actually exist in that folder?  Do you have permission to run it?  You appear to have enough backslashes, but the Windows APIs (but not the `cmd.exe` program and equivalents) accept `/` (slash) as a synonym for ``\`` (backslash).

Comment: Yes, the file exist and I have full control over it.

Comment: If the `fopen()` can't open it, then either the name in the program is wrong or there is a problem with the file on the disk. You might be able to find out more about what wrong with `errno` (from `<errno.h>`) and `strerror()` (from `<string.h>`). Basically, though, if the file doesn't open, there is a problem with either the program or the file name — take your pick, but we can't easily solve it for you remotely. You could consider passing the file name as a command line argument and opening the file specified on the command line. That allows you to test alternative names without recompiling.

Answer (score 3):

Use rewind(f) function.
It reset file pointer back to head, so after rewind() file as same as after 1st fopen().
For details, see: http://linux.die.net/man/3/rewind

Answer (score 0):

a) `fseek` to the beginning

or

b) Close the file before reopening